# Cloudflare Bot Protection with subdomains

Tags: javascript, nginx, cloudflare

I own a domain, example.com, which houses a website, and a subdomain, search.example.com, where a search server is installed.

Visitors interact with the website (created with Vue) and multiple client-initiated calls are made to the search server on the search.example.com subdomain.

On this site, the Managed Challenge is enabled. As part of a business subscription, I've installed this safeguard because the site is frequently targeted by web scrapers/bots, thus necessitating multiple rules for the activation of a Cloudflare captcha or JavaScript challenge.

I've run into an issue where, if a client connects using a "bad ip" source and successfully completes the captcha on the primary domain, this action doesn't carry over to the search server. Consequently, the main website loads, but the subdomain with the search API does not.

Both the main website and the search server are proxied through Cloudflare. They share the same root domain and reside under the same business account.

What's the ideal solution for this problem? Or might there be a setting I overlooked that enables the captcha cookie to be shared across both sites?

I'm able to proxy the search engine on a subfolder of the primary domain if nothing else works , but I prefer to have 2 different endpoints that is easier to manage and eventually scale up.